# What does it mean when there is a number to the left of a summation sigma?

Tags: induction

Trying to read Simple Wikipedia's Mathematical Induction article:

https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction

In many of the images, like this one:
https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/8aca5140d2bef31cc6ec27c34ace175533d0685d

There is a 2 to the <strike>right</strike> sorry, left of the summation symbol. What does it mean?

Comment: It's just a multiplicative factor. You should read it as "2 times the sum of...".

Comment: 2 * the sum of all of those numbers leading up to n (aka, 2 * n)? It's not really clicking with me...

Comment: $2 \times \left(\sum_{k=1}^n k\right) = n(n+1)$.

Comment: Ok, so the idea is that you keep adding up until what you're adding is the number n. And that first image I linked is rewritten from https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/0197730674f8dd57d86dbd401f9eb19fb5397e07 with the 1/2 taken from the left and added as a times 2 on the right. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have $a\sum_{b=1}^{c}d$, that means you multiply $a$ by $\sum_{b=1}^{c}d$.
Thus, you take $2$ and multiply it by $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k$.

Comment: I believe it does. I told user156964 what a number to the right of a summation means.

Comment: You are right. OP edited to ask what a number to left means. Your answer is useful - I upvoted.